# Windows 7 BSOD with Service Exception Error and Randomly Reboots

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

I've got a windows 7 laptop that BSOD with a Service Exception Error when I connect to a wireless network. It also does it when it's just sitting still doing nothing. I ran bluescreenview and here are the last four BSOD's from today:

==================================================
  Dump File         : 051210-18642-01.dmp
  Crash Time        : 5/12/2010 8:36:14 AM
  Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
  Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
  Parameter 1       : 00000000`c000001d
  Parameter 2       : fffff880`00000000
  Parameter 3       : fffff880`06fda160
  Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
  Caused By Driver  : Ntfs.sys
  Caused By Address : Ntfs.sys+7f030
  File Description  : 
  Product Name      : 
  Company           : 
  File Version      : 
  Processor         : x64
  Computer Name     : 
  Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\051210-18642-01.dmp
  Processors Count  : 2
  Major Version     : 15
  Minor Version     : 7600
  ==================================================

==================================================
  Dump File         : 051210-16551-01.dmp
  Crash Time        : 5/12/2010 8:41:04 AM
  Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
  Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
  Parameter 1       : 00000000`c000001d
  Parameter 2       : fffff880`00000000
  Parameter 3       : fffff880`06f40160
  Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
  Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
  Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+70600
  File Description  : NT Kernel & System
  Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
  Company           : Microsoft Corporation
  File Version      : 6.1.7600.16539 (win7_gdr.100226-1909)
  Processor         : x64
  Computer Name     : 
  Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\051210-16551-01.dmp
  Processors Count  : 2
  Major Version     : 15
  Minor Version     : 7600
  ==================================================

==================================================
  Dump File         : 051210-17269-01.dmp
  Crash Time        : 5/12/2010 8:45:51 AM
  Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
  Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
  Parameter 1       : 00000000`c000001d
  Parameter 2       : fffff880`00000000
  Parameter 3       : fffff880`07db1160
  Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
  Caused By Driver  : Ntfs.sys
  Caused By Address : Ntfs.sys+7f030
  File Description  : 
  Product Name      : 
  Company           : 
  File Version      : 
  Processor         : x64
  Computer Name     : 
  Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\051210-17269-01.dmp
  Processors Count  : 2
  Major Version     : 15
  Minor Version     : 7600
  ==================================================

==================================================
  Dump File         : 051210-19453-01.dmp
  Crash Time        : 5/12/2010 5:46:25 PM
  Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
  Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
  Parameter 1       : 00000000`c000001d
  Parameter 2       : fffff880`00000000
  Parameter 3       : fffff880`02625160
  Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
  Caused By Driver  : win32k.sys
  Caused By Address : win32k.sys+2d4201
  File Description  : 
  Product Name      : 
  Company           : 
  File Version      : 
  Processor         : x64
  Computer Name     : 
  Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\051210-19453-01.dmp
  Processors Count  : 2
  Major Version     : 15
  Minor Version     : 7600
  ==================================================

Comment: anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Every dump blames a different driver for the crash and they may not always be the culprit. You can do advanced diagnosis using Windows Debugging Tool to find out the root cause.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Or you can upload the dumps somewhere and link to them, I would be happy to analyze them for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using a different wireless chip.

[Microsoft says that the issue is generally hardware-related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms818997.aspx).

Comment: It's a dell laptop that came with windows vista and the free upgrade to windows 7. I ran hardware diagnostics all day yesterday on it and it came up clean: no hardware errors at all. This is a recent problem that just started in the past week or so.

Comment: The hardware diagnostics are not foolproof and there may be confounding issues.